# Catchable fatal error proplem in update mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysqli

I trying to but this code into my page

```
<?php
 include'../../includes/config.php';
mysqli_query($con, 'UPDATE action SET watch = watch+1 WHERE title = $title ');
?>
```

I getting this error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in

The problem is with `$con` variable because when I delete it the problem is done.

Please help me and forgive me for the spelling because I am Arabic.

Comment: You are using the wrong quotes. Should be doubles quotes so variable is interpreted as such. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: please be more visible and give me the solve

Comment: The issue I'm referring to may not be your issue but it will be an issue in the future. You query should be, `"UPDATE action SET watch = watch + 1 WHERE title = '$title'"`. The title needs to be in quotes because it is a string in SQL and the query needs to be in double quotes so the variable is interpreted.

Comment: Where is `$con` defined?

Comment: I figured that much what does it look? Like this `$con = mysqli_connect(.....`? Do you check for errors on the connecting?

Comment: $con=mysqli_connect("host","db","pass");

Comment: the last code 
<?php
 include'../../includes/config.php';
mysqli_query($con, 'UPDATE action SET watch = watch+1 WHERE title = $title ');
?>
is in varible its look like 

$content = " <?php
 include'../../includes/config.php';
mysqli_query($con, 'UPDATE action SET watch = watch+1 WHERE title = $title ');
?> ";

Comment: Does this connection work else where?

Comment: i'd sure like to know how this ends `Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in` but I have my own reason why your code's failing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you solved this or not, but I'm submitting the following answer just in case.

This query is failing for a few reasons.

```
mysqli_query($con, 'UPDATE action SET watch = watch+1 WHERE title = $title ');
                           ^^^^^^                                   ^^^^^^
```

Firstly, you're using a [MySQL reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html) called "action", then `$title` stands at being a string.

You need to wrap the "action" column name in ticks and `$title` in quotes, and possibly escaping that data should it contain anything that MySQL will complain about, such as apostrophes for instance.

I.e.:

```
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $title);
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `action` SET watch = watch+1 WHERE title = '$title' ");
```

Then in comments you added `$con=mysqli_connect("host","db","pass");`

The syntax is:

- host
- username
- password (if one is required)
- database

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Procedural style example, from the manual:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');

if (!$link) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Success... ' . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . "\n";

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

If you want to check if your query was truly successful, use `affected_rows()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

---

However, your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Footnotes:

- It's unsure as to where/how the `$title` variable is defined as, but seeing a word as such, tells me it's most likely a string and you may need to elaborate on that.